# Take a photo from the gallery using FileProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, android-fileprovider

I want to upload a photo from the gallery. When I check this code through the built-in emulator, this code works. But when I connect my phone (Xiaomi redmi note 7), this code stops working. Help please.
provider:

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.test.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/files"/>
    </provider>
```

files.xml

```
<paths>
<files-path
    name="testPhoto"
    path="."/>
```

Kotlin:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3)
    

    val intent: Intent =
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
    photo = File(this.applicationContext.filesDir,"photo.jpg")
    val uri = FileProvider
        .getUriForFile(this, "com.example.test.fileprovider", photo)
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
    
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when{
        resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK -> return
        requestCode == 2 -> {

            if (photo.exists()) {
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.path)
                imageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                imageView3.setImageDrawable(null)
            }
        }

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error you get when using it on your phone

Comment: I don't get any errors. "error" appears on the screen. Which I announced in Toast.

Comment: `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, ....` That statement makes no sense. As is using a FileProvider for ACTION_PICK. And that flag. All not needed. Further there is no upload code.

Comment: @blackapps 
Then what is the best way to make a download from the gallery?

Comment: I think you first should go for A way. Then the best way does not exist. And there was no upload code. A download from the gallery? What would that be?

Comment: @blackapps all right thank you